# Google fonts not applied to deployed react app on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, styled-components, google-font-api

I'm using styled-components for my app, and I imported a google font url in createGlobalStyle. :

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`



* {
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

After deploying the app, the font is not applied. I tried replacing the `@import` url from `https://fonts..` to `http://fonts..` and then currently `//fonts..`. These are some solutions I found that have worked for some, but not for me. What seems to be the problem here?

here is the link of the deployed app: `http://patorikkun.github.io/tip-calculator-app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the `@import` to top level, outside `* {}`

**From:**

```js
createGlobalStyle`
* {
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap");
    margin: 0;
    ...
}
...
}`;
```

**To:**

```js
createGlobalStyle`
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: 400;
}

...
}`;
```

From the [MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import):

> Imported rules must precede all other types of rules, except @charset rules;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I resolved it by copying the font-file to the 'public' folder in my react root, and then deploying it to GitHub.

Now I can refer to the font-file directly using;

`````
````
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OrgonPlan-Regular';
    src: url('/OrgonPlan-Regular.woff')  format('woff')
}
````
`````

Personally, I prefer serving my assets locally to avoid missing files due to downtime at third-party providers.